# Get the path of the first attached media (single.php)

Tags: attachments, media, paths

I'm currently developing a wallpaper website using WordPress and I'm trying to figure it out how to retrieve the path of the first attached media in the post so I can display the path in the post (e.g., `/wp-content/uploads/image.png`).
I tried a lot of WordPress functions such as `get_attached_media()` but I had no luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I finally found out how to display the path of the first attached media in the post. Here is the code I inserted in **single.php** to display the path at the end of the content :

```
<?php
$image_url = wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID ), 'full' );
$path = parse_url($image_url[0], PHP_URL_PATH);

echo /var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads$path;
?>
```

Result (for exemple):
/var/www/wordpress/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/image.jpg

Hope it will help someone else!

Answer (score 1):

I tried to write some snippet with the help of WordPress codex. Please check below and update it further as per your needs. I hope this helps:

```
global $post;

$args = array(
    'numberposts' => 1,
    'order' => 'ASC',
    'post_mime_type' => 'image',
    'post_parent' => $post->ID,
    'post_status' => null,
    'post_type' => 'attachment',
);

$attachments = get_children( $args );

if ( $attachments ) {
   foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {
      $image_attributes = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
      echo wp_get_attachment_url($attachment->ID);
      echo '<img src="' . wp_get_attachment_thumb_url( $attachment->ID ) . '" class="current">';
}
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I tried your code and it gives me a blank page with this error in the error log: http://pastebin.com/nJF0JCkC
Here is an exemple of what I'm tring to do: https://static.dyp.im/jfoq513ojV/84026be18c9e062145d4c41538d43968.PNG

Comment: The pastebin only shows the error message. Can you please update that with the code in your single.php file ? It does not seem the error which you have added in pastebin is from above code. I can take a look at your single.php code and assist further.

Comment: Ah... my bad. There was some extra code at the end of my code snippet. @Kika - thanks for the edits.

Comment: Thank you, the code worked. In fact, that's not really what I'm trying to achieve, because it doesn't give me the path as I showed you in the previous comment (static.dyp.im/jfoq513ojV/84026be18c9e062145d4c41538d43968.PNG). It gives me this: https://static.dyp.im/xpj1D938xa/8ebd5dd2e263e02b7b617cb58ffb26f0.PNG